# image plotted using matplotlib seems to have different colors than original JPEG image

Tags: image, macos, opencv, matplotlib, colors

The screenshot below compares the same image plotted using matplotlib on the left and Mac preview on the right.

[image: Color comparison of images]

Code for plotting the image using matplotlib is also fairly simple.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import skimage

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Color check.')
parser.add_argument('--image', required=False,metavar="path or URL to image")
args = parser.parse_args()

image = skimage.io.imread(args.image)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

As you can see the colors are visibly different in the two images. Why is this happening and which one should I trust to be the correct color representation?

**EDIT:**

I plotted the image using opencv's imshow and it looks fine.

[image: cv2 imshow plot]

and here is the code:

```
import argparse
import cv2

windowName = "image"
cv2.namedWindow(windowName,cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(windowName, 600,600)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Color check.')
parser.add_argument('--image', required=False,metavar="path or URL to image")
args = parser.parse_args()

image = cv2.imread(args.image)
cv2.imshow(windowName, image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The disagreement probably comes from the difference in [colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) used by the two programs. While Mac Preview is colorspace aware, and therefore should display images using the proper colorspace in which they are created/tagged, matplotlib uses the [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) colorspace.

I would say that the color representation used by Mac Preview is most likely the one also used by the creator of the image, therefore the one I would pick.

Comment: cv2.imshow seems to produce the right image and I'm guessing it uses sRGB as well. Thoughts?

Comment: I think [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0af3894ec8b239815e8a9075099805991a) can manage different colorspaces and probably chooses the right one las Mac Preview does.